# Select a div and append data

Tags: jquery

I have the following form

```
<form action="" class="ink-form">
    <fieldset class="">
        <div class="control-group required">
            <div class="column-group gutters">
                <label for="name" class="large-15 content-right">Link</label>
                <div class="control large-60 append-button">
                    <span><input name="link" type="text" id="name"></span>
                    <button id="convert" class="ink-button"><i class="icon-search"></i> Convert</button>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="large-15"></div>
    <div id="alertBox" teste="POP" class="large-50 medium-50 small-100">

    </div>
</form>
```

Using jquery I do `var form = $(this).parentsUntil("form");` to get the form when the button is clicked. Now I want to select the `alertBox div` to appended some data. In a older project I has the following function

```
function alertMessage(selector, type, message) {

  var typeText;
  if (type == "error")
    typeText = "Erro";
  else if (type == "success")
    typeText = "Sucesso";
  else if (type == "info")
    typeText = "Info";

  selector.append("<div id=\"alert\" class=\"ink-alert basic " + type + "\" style=\"display:none;\"><button class=\"ink-dismiss\">&times;</button><p><b>" + typeText + ":</b> " + message + "</p></div>");
  selector.find('div[id=alert]').show(500);
}
```

and called it using `alertMessage($(form).find('div[id=alertBox]'), "success", "O ficheiro foi importado com sucesso!");` but now it isn't working on a new project. I don't know if it is related with jQuery new version or an error :s

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/metRo_/bCQ3y/

Comment: why not use: alertMessage($('#alertBox'), "success", "O ficheiro foi importado com sucesso!");

Comment: I think I reproduce it using jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/metRo_/bCQ3y/

Comment: w3jimmy I wanted to change the alertbox related with the form I'm working on.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bCQ3y/1/

Comment: Ids must be unique to the HTML document, so there is no point in something like $(form).find('div[id=alertBox]').

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Javascript to this (looks like JSFiddle itself doesn't like the unspecific 'form' selector):

```
$('#convert').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parentsUntil("form .ink-form");
    alertMessage($(form).find('div[id=alertBox]'), "success", "O ficheiro foi importado com sucesso!");
    alert("teste");
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bCQ3y/4/)

However, just to reiterate what others have said:

- IDs in `HTML` should be unique, otherwise use classes with `.selector`s
- Might be tidier to change your selector to `$('#alertBox')`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this

```
var form = $(this).parentsUntil("form");
```

it does not give you the form element, as per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/)

Description: Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object.

So this is returning you this element `<div class="control-group required">` and this does not contain the `alertBox` so your this selector

```
$(form).find('div[id=alertBox]')
```

will not find any element.

Update your paerentsUntil selector to

```
var form = $(this).parents("form")[0];
```

then it will work or better provide some id to selector and select directly

```
<form id='sample' ...> $('#sample')
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/bCQ3y/5/